# Gesture typing on multiple languages?

Tags: nexus-7, 4.2-jelly-bean, gesture-typing

I recently played with my friend's Nexus 7 and tried the gesture typing. And I'm surprised it only works on user's locale keyboard. It lacks Ukrainian dictionary too :( , but that's another question.

It works only on Russian keyboard. Dictionaries for all English variants are present, I even tried all three English keyboards (QWERTY, UK, US). Android version is 4.2.2.

Is that a bug? A reported one?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about your specific issue, but Swiftkey 4 has gesture typing that's worked for me in multiple languages (English and French).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is a bug, my Nexus 4 is on the English locale and with a Russian input language gesture typing works.

Perhaps you've installed an app that gives you the Russian keyboard, it wouldn't support gesture typing by default.

Comment: No, it's definitely the default keyboard. Do both of them  work for you? Can you please add your selected keyboard layouts?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a couple of bugs here. It doesn't work with qwerty layout. It *does* work with UK and US though, but the trick here is to disable and enable again "Gesture input" option *after*  needed dictionaries were installed.